# How to travel with huge sum of money?

Tags: international-travel, money

I know that carrying it in my bag or wallet or whatever is a bad idea, but placing it on a credit card would raise questions to authorities as it was old peoples' inheritance from "under the bed."

I would be traveling from Latvia to Sweden, Norway and Netherlands, and the currency is Euros.

I'm not trying to evade taxes - it's money saved up throughout a few decades and not by me. I simply inherited it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about evading taxes and other regulations.

Comment: You do realise that in many places, large sums of money have to be declared anyway? E.g. http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/customs/customs_controls/cash_controls/index_en.htm

Comment: Where from and to? Because that effects regulations that may apply - and in what currency?

Also, as credit cards are a way of borrowing money, would be odd to "put money on them"

I don't see any part of the question requesting that appropriate procedures are evaded, so don't agree it needs closing.

Comment: It's not a question about evading taxes, it's money that was saved up throughout I don't know, 60 years?

Comment: From Latvia to Sweden, Netherlands and Norway. Euros.

Comment: It seems that Norway is likley to be the biggest problem, being a non-EU state.

Comment: Norway has Shenghen agreement, so I don't even need a passport traveling there, only my ID card. And it's less than 10,000eu, by the way, more like 9,000.

Comment: Schengen is a passport and immigration agreement, not customs, which is more likley to effect this.

Comment: @Relaxed Those regulations are for entering or leaving the EU, and do not apply for travel within the EU.  Norway, however, requires declaring sums exceeding NOK 25,000 (under EUR 3000): http://www.toll.no/en/international/english/travelling-to-and-from-norway/you-must-declare-currency-with-a-value-of-more-than-nok-25000/

Comment: @jpatokal That's why it says “many places” and “e.g.”, the OP hadn't even specified he intended to travel in Europe when I wrote the comment. But there are many other such rules, including when travelling between EU countries.

Comment: @Jack Well, it's not huge then, you could consider cash or do a bank transfer, I don't think anybody cares.

Comment: @Jack Either it's completely above board and you can simply put it on your bank account and spend it as you go with a credit or debit card. Or you are concerned about having to pay some estate tax and then you *are* trying to evade taxes. Realistically, for €9000, you might even get away with it regardless.

Comment: I've been through customs with a significant amount of physical cash before (I don't know if it was this much), and it really is just about declaring it and being sure you're under the cash limit. Safety is the real concern here.

Comment: Unless it's changed in the last two years, Deloitte & Touche (huge US accounting firm) says there's [no inheritance tax](http://www2.deloitte.com/content/dam/Deloitte/global/Documents/Tax/dttl-tax-latviaguide-2013.pdf) in Latvia.

Comment: If you're trying to move around with a relatively large amount of cash or gold, and who doesn't, just *face up to yourself* and do it.  Idiots give advice like "hide under shirt" etc.  The overwhelming advice from working professionals is  ***keep your mouth absolutely shut***.  That's s-h-u-t, shut, shut.  DO NOT tell your children, spouse, grandma or anyone you are carrying cash.  NOBODY.  Be discrete and calm.  Tell nobody.

Comment: @JoeBlow I agree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's at least two separate facets to consider here.

**Legally**, you're in the clear.  Restrictions covering [traveling within the EU](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/carry/alcohol-tobacco-cash/index_en.htm) and [travel to/from from the EU](http://www.toll.no/en/international/english/travelling-to-and-from-norway/you-must-declare-currency-with-a-value-of-more-than-nok-25000/) only require you to declare amounts exceeding EUR 10,000.

Norway, however, being outside the EU, [requires you to declare amounts over NOK 25,000](http://www.toll.no/en/international/english/travelling-to-and-from-norway/you-must-declare-currency-with-a-value-of-more-than-nok-25000/) (~EUR 2,800 at time of writing) or face a 20% penalty, although it's a little unclear to me where/how exactly you're supposed to declare if coming from a fellow Schengen country.

**Safety** is a bigger concern, as carrying around EUR 9,000 just seems like a really bad idea.  The right thing to do would be to deposit it at a Latvian bank, declare its origin and pay any applicable taxes, and then you can transfer it easily to other countries, withdraw it from ATMs, use it to pay credit card bills, etc.

If you wish to stick to plain old cash, then [the answers to this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24726/how-to-safely-transport-money?rq=1) and [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/avoiding-the-travellers-fanny-pack-money-belt) have some advice for you, although most of it boils down to "don't".  In short, divide your money in multiple places, preferably directly on your body but in unobvious places (hidden pockets in pants, etc) — this way you minimize the risk of losing them through both theft and violent robbery.  The latter isn't a huge concern in Sweden or Norway, although one of the three times somebody has tried to pickpocket me did occur in Stockholm's T-Centralen...

Comment: Actually, the EU rules are just extra rules on top of national rules, there is nothing preventing EU countries from requiring people to declare cash when travelling within the EU and several do.

Comment: You are correct, but per the EU guidance I just linked to, they can only do so when the amount exceeds EUR 10k or equivalent.

Comment: Well, my main concern is safety, especially on my way there, as I will be going through other countries by bus for maybe 20 hours or so... I will be sleeping and everything on the bus. Anyway, there aren't applicable taxes, I don't know where the money came from. The person just saved it for many years until he died and left it for me by word, not any paper... Meaning I'd have trouble with authorities if I put 9k to my account. Isn't there something I can buy and cash in without my name on it there?

Comment: This is more a question for Money.SE, but I don't understand what "trouble with authorities" you're worried about?   Go to the bank, if they ask say it's from an inheritance (or deposit slowly in sub-1000e increments if they won't take it without documentation), and declare it on your tax return.

Comment: Here in the US, it's required to do some extra paperwork for US $10,000 transactions and up, but a one-time deposit is highly unlikely to attract attention from the authorities. I once deposited $4000 in cash from selling an extra car and the teller didn't blink. I would be terrified of losing $9000 over the course of a vacation, either by accident or as a crime victim. I strongly advise against it.

Comment: I've deposited $5-7000 or more at a time at banks in the USA using both ATMs and tellers, many times, and it hasn't been given any particular attention that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

When you carry cash with you on an airline trip, you should take some very basic steps to keep from becoming a victim of theft, or from losing your money by accident.

1.Avoid traveling with large amounts of cash.

2.If you have to take cash, keep it in a carry on bag.

3.Never put your cash, financial instruments, or precious metals in a checked bag.

4.Keep your cash and other valuables out of public view.

5.Keep your baggage and belongings in sight when passing through a security checkpoint.

6.If your carry on baggage must be searched, insist on keeping your bag in sight.

7.If asked about the amount of money in your baggage by a TSA agent or other responsible authority, tell the truth.

8.If you suspect that you have been a victim of theft, contact an airport police officer or other law enforcement representative immediately (note that TSA agents are not law enforcement agents)

If you suspect that a TSA screener or other screening area employee has stolen your property, contact a supervisor.

Comment: Is that copied and posted from somewhere? The OP has not said they're flying, and is certainly not flying in the USA.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there are no restriction of holding cash and declare it when traveling in EU countries but I think carrying such a big money during traveling without safety is not a good idea.

Comment: How is there no restriction?

Comment: As shown by jpatokal, there **are** such restrioctions.